# PureCSS stop page reload on form submit but retain form validation

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, yui-pure-css

I'm trying to use PureCSS forms in my web app and I can't figure out how to retain the nifty form validation while stopping the page reload.

I know I can stop the page reload using `onsubmit="return false;"`

Then I can use AJAX to post the form data using `onClick="PostSettings();"`, where PostSettings() is my javascript function containing the AJAX request. I also have to include `event.preventDefault();` at the top of that function to stop the reload.

Unfortunately these steps which stop the reload also stop the nice in-built PureCSS validation.

Is there a way to retain that without triggering the page reload or will I need to make my own validation in the javascript?

FYI, here's the html:

```
<button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary"
  id="save-simulation-button" onClick="PostSettings();" 
  onsubmit="return false;">
    <i     class="fa fa-save"></i> Submit Simulation Parameters
</button>
```

Comment: how about removing onclick and having onsubmit="PostSettings();"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your replies Lucas and Vignesh -- they didn't quite solve the problem, but they got me thinking and I developed a solution:

In the html I had to add a return here: `onClick="return PostSettings();"`

Then in the javascript I return `true` or `false` depending on whether or not the form passes validation, which I have to check:

```
function PostSettings() {
    //event.preventDefault(); <<- commented out per Vigneshs suggestion

    var name = $("#simulation-name").val(); // jquery to get form values
    var description = $("#description").val();

    // Code to validate form: name and description cannot be blank
    if (name === "" || description === "") {
        console.log("name or description fields cannot be blank");
        return true; // <<- returning true allows PureCSS validation to continue
    }

    // Code passed validation so post the data...
    // POST code omitted for brevity

    return false; // <<- returning false stops the page reload
}
```

So in summary, returning `true` allows the PureCSS form validation to take place as per normal (and there's no page reload because the form hasn't passed validation). And when the form passes validation I return `false` to stop the page reload -- this also stops any other default events of the PureCSS form, but that's okay because I manually checked if it validated in the javascript.

Hope this helps others who want to accomplish this in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Use 'return false' instead of event.preventDefault() inside the 'PostSettings()' method.

Answer (score 0):

You only need a *onsubmit="return MyValidFunction();"* **in the Form tag and nothing else** in the "submit" button

When the form is not ok PureCSS make the validation with his message, When All is ok call your *"MyValidFunction()"* function

```
function MyFunction() {
   /// your Ajax Code here
   return false;
}

<form class="pure-form" onsubmit="return PostSettings();">
  <input id="form_url" type="url" class="pure-input-1-3">
   <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-input-1-1">OK</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Adding `onsubmit="event.stopPropagation()"` in the form tag prevents the refresh when the form is valid, and retains validation flags when it's invalid.